# axios: post a get request with parameters in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, axios

I'm trying to post a GET request to a laravel routes but I'm getting a 404 (Not Found)

ajax call

```
   axios.get('/statisticsJSON', {
        params: {
          annee: 2017,
          mois: 06,
          jour: 15,
        }
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log('Les donnees via ajax');
        console.log( response.data);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/statisticsJSON/{annee}/{mois}/{jour}', 'EmploiController@showStatisticsJSON')
   ->name('statsJSON')
   ->where('annee', '^(19|20)\d{2}$')
   ->where('mois', '^(19|20)\d{2}$')
   ->where('jour', '^(19|20)\d{2}$');
```

controller

```
public function showStatisticsJSON(Request $request, $annee=null, $mois=null, $jour=null)
{
    //
    $annee = $request->get('annee');
    $mois = $request->get('mois');
    $jour = $request->get('jour');
    $emplois = Emploi::whereYear('POSTDATE', '=', $annee)
          ->whereMonth('POSTDATE', '=', $mois)
          ->whereDay('POSTDATE', '=', $jour)
          ->get();
    return response()->json(emplois ,200,[],JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}
```

link generated

```
http://localhost:8000/statisticsJSON?annee=2017&mois=6&jour=15
```

Comment: Please don't say "post a get request", heh. POST and GET are two totally different types of HTTP request - very confusing terminology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending query parameters, not route parameters as it is. Laravel expects

http://localhost:8000/statisticsJSON/2017/6/15

in order for it to match. Build the url string for `axios.get(my_url,` first and omit the `params: {}`.

Comment: Thanks btl! but I kindda simplify my code for SO but I will need my `params ` because each time I will click on a date I need to retrieve the `jour=date.getDate(); mois= date.getMonth() + 1; annee=date.getFullYear();` so the url will be dynamic

Comment: ok thanks I get the diff between query parameter and route parameters

Comment: Good to hear, glad I could help =D